# My question still on hold after adding details?

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I have asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1363341/corrupted-downloads-when-retrieving-files-directly-via-isp-connection-but-things) and it got put on hold for the lack of details and for asking many question.

I have edited it to one question and I have added the details that have been requested from me and could provide, and it doesn't really help to ask for details and not be specific as what are those details.

So what else is needed to remove the hold ?

Comment: I'm not convinced, but I've reopened it.

Comment: @DavidPostill can you elaborate more ?don't reopen it if you are not convinced

Comment: It's a better question. Let's leave it open for now.